# Can I Update an Attribute of a Model After the Page Has Beeen Loaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I am working on project with `spring-mvc`. I am a new user of `spring-mvc`. I just want to make my concept clear about - "Updating an attribute of a model object after the page has been loaded". For simplicity I am not adding the code from my project. Please consider the code snippet. I have an class `'FeatureProfileModel.java'` in which I have a variable/attribute `'dynamicVars'` -

```
public class FeatureProfileModel{
 List<DynamicVar> dynamicVars;
}
```

This `'FeatureProfileModel'` object is bind with a jsp - `'featureProfile.jsp'` as a model. When the `'featureProfile.jsp'` page loaded then the `'dynamicVars'` was empty. This `'dynamicVars'` will be generated after a link has been clicked. Is it possible to update this 'dynamicVars' after the page has been loaded. Please notice here I don't want to reload the page after the click event I just want to update the model `'FeatureProfileModel'`.

Comment: Don't include things like "Spring" in the title. Thats what tags are for.

Comment: @Razib sowmhow just load that particular div/or portion of jsp, segregate your jsp or fire an ajax call, get response data from server,  set html.